# Is it worth to kill weekly bosses for 60 resin if I don't need their talent level-up drops anymore?

Tags: genshin-impact

As of 2.6, there's 6 weekly bosses. You can kill 3 for 30 resin each, and the remaining 3 cost 60 resin each.

But for example, assume I don't need the talent drops from Stormterror anymore, is it still worth paying 60 resin for the remaining drops?

Answer (score 3):

The only reason to do the weekly bosses are the billets, their talent drops (and Dream Solvent to swap them). If you aren't in need of any of these, you can very well do other things with higher yield:

Artifacts (Gladiators and Wanderers Troupe) and character ascension materials(gems):
Farm normal bosses for 40 instead of 60 resin. They also drop more specific character ascension matherials of one chosen element.

**Do the 30-reson bosses and if you're not in hard need for billets, farm normal bosses or do domains instead of the 60-resin-bosses.** I'd recommend to take the 3 30-resin-fights and leave the rest. You should choose which 3 you take in needs of current or future characters.

After all, you can only do each weekly boss *once* weekly, so it's pretty hard to farm the talent materials if you need them and don't already have them.

Answer (score 1):

If you still lack billets (12% chance) or dream solvent (33% chance), it's kinda worth it since you can't get them anywhere else, but otherwise, not so much, since it only gives small amount of artifacts (average 4.1/2.9/1.2 3☆/4☆/5☆) compared to doing artifact domains 3 times (average 10.7/7.4/3.2 3☆/4☆/5☆). Well, you also get on average about 12 slivers per weekly boss, but that's not valuable enough to be worth it as a goal.

Comment: Your clearly do not factor in opportunity cost of a severly limiting resource - why ist that?

Comment: @Akixkisu probably because like they just said currently the trounce domain / wolf world boss are the only unlimited source of weapon billets. You can only get a few "free" ones from quests, limited events and such but once you exhaust those the bosses become the only possible source for more - albeit with a really horrible rate. At that point it really becomes a matter of how desperate you are for a weapon.

Comment: While the 5* are almost always superior to the craftable options, they require to spend fates on the weapon banner or the standard one - both of which low spender are pushed to ignore in favor of the limited character one. This means that most F2P / low spender will mostly use 4* weap from the gacha.... but limited banner really LOVES to give you the three rate up 4 star characters instead. As such some players could really use one of those craftable options. Whiteblind for Itto/Noelle comes to mind

Comment: @Ꮢedacted thanks for the explanation! For more details, billet drop rate is 12%, and dream solvent is 33%, so it's not that bad *if you want to get them*. Akixkisu, I'm not sure what you mean. If your goal is to get billet or dream solvent, then do it. If your goal to get more artifacts is more valuable than getting more billets, then don't do it. My answer just says that it's only useful for billet and dream solvent.

Comment: @justhalf yep, collected data seems to indicate that the billets have a drop rate close to 10-15%. The real issue is that even when you get one, assuming equal distribution you still have a 1/5 chance to get the actual one you needed (that Whiteblind won't get crafted out of a bow billet...). Like you said, it is really up to the player to decide if they want to gamble for a low chance to get a weapon they need when no other options are available. Anyway, in case you need any other personal suggestion, you can leave a message [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132902)

Comment: I don't agree with the implied assumption that accounts that want billets and Dream Solvents wouldn't benefit from other activities more. This advice is only applicable to fringe scenarios that don't fit the majority of gamers and their goals. The advice here will detract from the average player's experience.

Answer (score -1):

### No, it is actively a suboptimal choice as you could choose to go for specific drops with that resin instead.

When you use https://traveler.gg/domain-and-boss-loot-drop-rates/ to compare drop rates, you will notice that billets and dream solvent are already factored in the overall value — which is a consistent resin value compared to other resin options. Since you don't want them, you are losing out on a small amount of value by doing them.

Resin is what gets you things in Geshin Impact. If you spend your resin on something, you can't spend it on something else. This is a tangabile opportunity cost that you will incur every week if you choose to do these bosses. Your steady weekly resin gain is 1260 units. Each weekly boss clear removes almost 5% of your available funds for that week that you could otherwise spend on activities that provide you the resources you actually need to accomplish your goals.

You are already receiving a steady supply of both billets and Dream Solvent by doing the discounted weekly bosses. You will want to take advantage of the discounted weekly bosses in the future. If you gain additonal material now, you reduce the value of the future material that you gain then since there are finite use cases for billets and Dream Solvents.

You are slowing down the space of gaining material that you want now that you would use to accomplish the goals that you want to realise for your account by accumulating a less targeted increase of resources instead of a specific increase in resources, so realising your account goals slows down.

If you enjoy clearing the bosses, you can always do so without collecting their rewards.

Comment: I didn't downvote, and thanks for the link to traveler.gg, but I guess one can also argue that we can put different personal values for different loots. For example, if I feel I'm done with artifacts and talents, and just need that billet, for example, then of course spending 60 resin for a 12% chance to get a billet is worth it.

Comment: @justhalf To a degree we can do that, but they also have a finite use case. We can very confidently assume that only a few of these weapons are worth crafting since there are use cases for them — while the majority of crafted weapons are worthless except for collective purposes. Even Dream Solvent has a finite use case - though they can be more widely applicable.

Comment: Since there is an objective value to them (that we can assess case by case subjectively) we can look at any given account and evaluate whether they add value to the account or detract value due to their opportunity cost that prevents gathering specific resources that that account wants to access.

Comment: And we can also confidently state that most accounts want other resources more than they want either Dream Solvent or billets due to the reward architecture of the game, we can therefore confidently state as well that for most people doing these weekly bosses will reduce the effective value gain for the account. There are of course very few exceptions to the general principle.

Comment: Well, the reasoning you put here is an average statistics over many players, as you mentioned. But we are giving an advice here. And an advice needs to take into account the current situation of the player. Your reasoning is similar to this: "We play a solo game where we start with the number 1, and at each turn, we can either +1 or x2. Our goal is to reach 100, but we lose if we exceed 100." Now say we have 100 players, most of them has reached 50+. They can no longer x2, so they should +1. On average, the value of x2 is lower than +1. But clearly a right advice depends on current number

Comment: @justhalf that oversimplifies the issue and doesn't accurately reflect that you still do weekly bosses since you want to take advantage of the discount.

Comment: @justhalf An account that would benefit from gaining 4 star billet weapons will almost certainly profit from doing other activities more. And if we give advice we should give solid advice that is applicable to the stated problem.

Comment: Well, if you think so, so be it :) I'll just end with this: not all players have the same goal to play the game. If my goal is to get Whiteblind as quickly as possible, then of course doing as many weekly bosses as I can is the best thing I can do. If my goal is to optimize my resource over many years, and I'm okay with not getting Whiteblind in the near future, then just wait for next week. My point is that the second goal is not the only valid objective goal. The first goal I mentioned is also valid, and the advice for players with that goal is different.

Comment: @justhalf The question has a clearly framed problem and my advice applies to it, and yours applies to a different unstated problem.